# How to extract values from json body where key values has multiple keys and one value

Tags: sql, json

I have a json body stored in a column in my SQL database which i have been trying to extract the label.def and the value and match them together in a table output .

Essentially I am trying to output the following table:

| Address | Suburb | Alternate Phone Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 Jolly Street | Crazytown | 041234567 |

```
    "customCheckoutFields": [
        {
            "label": {
                "def": "Address",
                "en": "Address"
            },
            "value": "123 Jolly street "
        },
        {
            "label": {
                "def": "Suburb",
                "en": "Suburb"
            },
            "value": "Crazytown "
        },
        {
            "label": {
                "def": "State",
                "en": "State"
            },
            "value": "Queensland "
        },
        {
            "label": {
                "def": "Postcode",
                "en": "Postcode"
            },
            "value": "12345"
        },
        {
            "label": {
                "def": "Alternate Phone Number",
                "en": "Alternate Phone Number"
            },
            "value": "041234567"
      }
  ]
```

I tried using the `JSON_VALUE` function which would extract the value but i was unable to get the result and ended up with blanks.

Comment: tag with database platform please and show your SQL attempt